# Enabling SSSE3 flag on a VM running on KVM

Tags: cpu, virtualization, qemu, linux-kvm

How do I forward the SSSE3 flag from my host server to VM while using KVM? I tried the following.

My QEMU version is `qemu-kvm-1.5.3`. My host server has the SSSE3 flag enabled (output cut for brevity):

```
[host]# lscpu | grep Flags | grep ssse3
Flags:                 .... vmx ssse3 ...
```

where the model is:

```
[host]# lscpu | grep "Model name"
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz
```

I deploy a VM using KVM, and I tried the following CPU options in the XML file:

1. Host passthrough so I could forward all flags:

```
  <cpu mode='host-passthrough'>
    <topology sockets='1' cores='1' threads='1'/>
  </cpu>
```

2. Just enabling the SSSE3 flag:

```
  <cpu>
    <topology sockets='1' cores='1' threads='1'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ssse3'/>
  </cpu>
```

However in the VM, I am unable to see the SSSE3 flag in the `lscpu` output. In fact, the `host-passthrough` mode does not even show an Intel CPU in the VM output

```
[host]$ lscpu | grep "Model name"
Model name:            QEMU Virtual CPU version 1.5.3
```

Comment: Try to start it using the parameter `qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cpu +ssse3`.

Comment: I ran the VM using a typical XML file then used virsh to define the VM using the XML. Can I somehow use this XML file as an input to the ```qemu-system-x86_64``` command?